# Execute certain stages based on job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am still confused about how to execute stage, based on Jenkin's job.

Let's say I created the following jobs:

- buildJob : this will just execute the prepare + build stages, triggered when the code is commited into git/svn
- integrationJob : prepate + build + test + deploy into integration server
- stagingJob : build + test + deploy into staging server
- nexusJob : deploy into nexus
- prodJob : deploy from nexus into production server, based on user's input

This is the Jenkinsfile :

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        maven 'maven.1.8.0' 
    }

    options {
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }

    environment {
        INTEGRATION_URL = "https://"        
        NEXUS_URL = "https://"        
        STAGING_URL = "https://"        
        PROD_URL = "https://"        
    }   

    stages {
        stage('=== Prepare ...') {
            steps {
                echo 'git checkout master + git pull ...' 
            }
        }

        stage('=== Build ...') {
            steps {
                echo 'build ...'
                sh 'mvn clean compile'
            }
        }

        stage('=== Test ...') {
            steps {
                echo 'test ...'
                sh 'mvn clean verify'
           }
        }

        stage('=== Release to Nexus...') {
            steps {
                echo 'mvn release:prepare release:perform ...'
           }           
        }

        stage('=== Deploy to ...') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploy ...'
           }           
        }
    }
}
```

One of the solutions is by implementing the 'when' condition, based on inout parameters (I saw this somewhere). But, is there any solutions WITHOUT human input ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pipeline script follow groovy syntax, you could try using if-else condition where you could pass the conditions for a specific stage execution, if that's easy for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any exemple ?